# I am setting an array of objects in localstorage using JSON.stringify(the_data), how do I reuse this data now?

Tags: javascript

I am building a flower picker, and there's a submit option.  Before the submit I am keeping track of the flower quantities using localStorage.

Each object representing a flower looks like this -

```
{
  flower_id: 1,
  qty: 3
}
```

Now, how can I reuse that in my angular controller?  because it is stored in localStorage as a string

```
[{flower_id: 1,qty: 3}]
```

, it counts the length of the value (23) instead of the array length.  How can I turn that back into a javascript object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JSON.parse() method on the string like this:

```
JSON.parse("[{flower_id: 1,qty: 3}]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON.parse:

```
var object = JSON.parse(stringFromLocalStorage);
```